# How to change any data type into a string?

Tags: python

How can I change any data type into a string in Python?

Comment: `str(var)`? is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Do you want a human-readable string representation of the data?  Or do you want a byte-oriented view of the memory containing the data?

Comment: Be careful with the type of the data you want to change. See answer below

Comment: does every class/type in python always allows `str` to be called on it without error?

Answer (score 150):

```
myvariable = 4
mystring = str(myvariable)  # '4'
```

also, alternatively try repr:

```
mystring = repr(myvariable) # '4'
```

This is called "conversion" in python, and is quite common.

Comment: I wouldn't use repr(myvariable) - it often returns information about class type, memory address etc. It's more useful for debugging. Use str(myvariable) for conversion to string and unicode(variable) for conversion to unicode.

Comment: What about unicode? Something like `str(u'ä')` will not work. However `repr(u'ä')` will work.

Comment: what about None and False?

Comment: does every class/type in python always allows `str` to be called on it without error?

Answer (score 74):

`str` is meant to produce a string representation of the object's data. If you're writing your own class and you want `str` to work for you, add:

```
def __str__(self):
    return "Some descriptive string"
```

`print str(myObj)` will call `myObj.__str__()`.

`repr` is a similar method, which generally produces information on the class info. For most core library object, `repr` produces the class name (and sometime some class information) between angle brackets. `repr` will be used, for example, by just typing your object into your interactions pane, without using `print` or anything else.

You can define the behavior of `repr` for your own objects just like you can define the behavior of `str`:

```
def __repr__(self):
    return "Some descriptive string"
```

`>>> myObj` in your interactions pane, or `repr(myObj)`, will result in `myObj.__repr__()`

Comment: It's probably true that the majority of core library objects by raw percentage return the `object.__repr__`-style angle-bracket representation, but many of the most commonly used ones do not. The rule of thumb for `repr` is that if it makes sense to return Python code that could be evaluated to produce the same object, do that, just like `str`, `frozenset`, and most other builtins do, but if it doesn't, use the angle-bracket form to make sure that what you return can't possibly be mistaken for a human-readable-and-evaluatable-as-source repr.

Comment: (Of course some of the builtins violate that rule of thumb—a `list` that includes itself returns something that not only looks like but is evaluable code, which evaluates to the wrong thing—but the core devs have never taken that as license to expand the same behavior into the stdlib.)

Comment: does every class/type in python always allows `str` to be called on it without error?

Comment: @CharlieParker yes; `__str__` is a function inherited from the object class, which is the root for all other classes in Python. https://docs.python.org/3/reference/datamodel.html#object.__str__

Answer (score 21):

I see all answers recommend using `str(object)`. It might fail if your object have more than ascii characters and you will see error like `ordinal not in range(128)`. This was the case for me while I was converting list of string in language other than English

I resolved it by using `unicode(object)`

Comment: in Python 3.0 onward, str(object) does unicode by default

Comment: does every class/type in python always allows `str` to be called on it without error?

Answer (score 14):

`str(object)` will do the trick.

If you want to alter the way object is stringified, define `__str__(self)` method for object's class. Such method has to return str or unicode object.

Comment: Which method is efficient? `str(any_var)` or `any_var.__str__()`

Comment: @Kedar.Aitawdekar: Even if there is noticeable difference in execution time (which I doubt, but I encourage you to vefiry it using `timeit` module), you should use `str(any_var)` since it's more readable for human and allows to benefit from cases when `any_var` defines `__repr__()` but doesn't define `__str__()`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply.

Comment: does every class/type in python always allows `str` to be called on it without error?

Comment: @CharlieParker : Yes, `str()` can be called freely on any Python object, including classes, modules, function objects etc. It is possible to implement `__str__` on a custom type in a way that would raise an exception, but generally speaking it's possible to make an error in any custom code. ;)

Answer (score 12):

Use the [`str`](http://docs.python.org/library/functions.html#str) built-in:

```
x = str(something)
```

Examples:

```
>>> str(1)
'1'
>>> str(1.0)
'1.0'
>>> str([])
'[]'
>>> str({})
'{}'

...
```

From the documentation:

> Return a string containing a nicely printable representation of an object. For strings, this returns the string itself. The difference with repr(object) is that str(object) does not always attempt to return a string that is acceptable to eval(); its goal is to return a printable string. If no argument is given, returns the empty string, ''.

Comment: does every class/type in python always allows `str` to be called on it without error?

Answer (score 6):

With `str(x)`. However, every data type can define its own string conversion, so this might not be what you want.

Comment: This is an important yet rare consideration. Good that you mentioned it.

Answer (score 3):

You can use `%s` like below

```
>>> "%s" %([])
'[]'
```

Answer (score 1):

Just use `str` - for example:

```
>>> str([])
'[]'
```

Answer (score 1):

Be careful if you really want to "change" the data type. Like in other cases (e.g. changing the iterator in a `for` loop) this might bring up unexpected behaviour:

```
>> dct = {1:3, 2:1}
>> len(str(dct))
12
>> print(str(dct))
{1: 31, 2: 0}
>> l = ["all","colours"]
>> len(str(l))
18
```

Answer (score 0):

Use formatting:

```
"%s" % (x)
```

Example:

```
x = time.ctime(); str = "%s" % (x); print str
```

Output: 
**Thu Jan 11 20:40:05 2018**