# Convert Python ElementTree to string

Tags: python, xml, marshalling, elementtree

Whenever I call `ElementTree.tostring(e)`, I get the following error message:

```
AttributeError: 'Element' object has no attribute 'getroot'
```

Is there any other way to convert an ElementTree object into an XML string?

TraceBack:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Development/Python/REObjectSort/REObjectResolver.py", line 145, in <module>
    cm = integrateDataWithCsv(cm, csvm)
  File "Development/Python/REObjectSort/REObjectResolver.py", line 137, in integrateDataWithCsv
    xmlstr = ElementTree.tostring(et.getroot(),encoding='utf8',method='xml')
AttributeError: 'Element' object has no attribute 'getroot'
```

Answer (score 175, accepted):

`Element` objects have no `.getroot()` method. Drop that call, and the [`.tostring()`](https://docs.python.org/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring) call works:

```py
xmlstr = ElementTree.tostring(et, encoding='utf8')
```

You only need to use `.getroot()` if you have an [`ElementTree` instance](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.ElementTree).

Other notes:

- This produces a *bytestring*, which in Python 3 is the `bytes` type.
  If you must have a `str` object, you have two options:

  1. Decode the resulting bytes value, from UTF-8: `xmlstr.decode("utf8")`
  2. Use `encoding='unicode'`; this avoids an encode / decode cycle:

     ```py
     xmlstr = ElementTree.tostring(et, encoding='unicode')
     ```
- If you wanted the UTF-8 encoded bytestring value or are using Python 2, take into account that ElementTree doesn't properly detect `utf8` as the standard XML encoding, so it'll add a `<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf8'?>` declaration. Use `utf-8` or `UTF-8` (with a dash) if you want to prevent this. When using `encoding="unicode"` no declaration header is added.

Answer (score 78):

#### How do I convert `ElementTree.Element` to a String?

For Python 3:

```
xml_str = ElementTree.tostring(xml, encoding='unicode')
```

For Python 2:

```
xml_str = ElementTree.tostring(xml, encoding='utf-8')
```

---

#### Example usage (Python 3)

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

xml = ElementTree.Element("Person", Name="John")
xml_str = ElementTree.tostring(xml, encoding='unicode')
print(xml_str)
```

Output:

```
<Person Name="John" />
```

---

#### Explanation

[`ElementTree.tostring()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring) returns a bytestring by default in Python 2 & 3. This is an issue because Python 3 [switched to using Unicode for strings](https://medium.com/better-programming/strings-unicode-and-bytes-in-python-3-everything-you-always-wanted-to-know-27dc02ff2686).

> **In Python 2 you could use the `str` type for both text and binary data**.
> Unfortunately this confluence of two different concepts could lead to
> brittle code which sometimes worked for either kind of data, sometimes
> not. [...]
>
> To make the distinction between text and binary data clearer and more pronounced, **[Python 3] made text and binary data distinct types that cannot blindly be mixed together**.

<sup>Source: [*Porting Python 2 Code to Python 3*](https://docs.python.org/3/howto/pyporting.html#text-versus-binary-data)</sup>

If you know what version of Python is being used, you should specify the encoding as `unicode` or `utf-8`. For reference, I've included a comparison of `.tostring()` results between Python 2 and Python 3.

```
ElementTree.tostring(xml)
# Python 3: b'<Person Name="John" />'
# Python 2: <Person Name="John" />

ElementTree.tostring(xml, encoding='unicode')
# Python 3: <Person Name="John" />
# Python 2: LookupError: unknown encoding: unicode

ElementTree.tostring(xml, encoding='utf-8')
# Python 3: b'<Person Name="John" />'
# Python 2: <Person Name="John" />

ElementTree.tostring(xml).decode()
# Python 3: <Person Name="John" />
# Python 2: <Person Name="John" />
```

<sup>Note: While [`xml_str = ElementTree.tostring().decode()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#bytes.decode) is compatible with both Python 2 & 3, Christopher Rucinski pointed out that this method [fails when dealing with non-Latin characters](https://stackoverflow.com/a/63943641/3357935)).</sup>

Thanks to [Martijn Peters](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15304229/convert-python-elementtree-to-string/48671499?noredirect=1#comment84342152_48671499) for pointing out that the `str` datatype changed between Python 2 and 3.

---

#### Why not use str()?

In most scenarios, using [`str()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str) would be the "[canonical](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3205525/3357935)" way to convert an object to a string. However, using `str()` with `Element` returns the object's location in memory as a hexstring, rather than a string representation of the object's data.

```
from xml.etree import ElementTree

xml = ElementTree.Element("Person", Name="John")
print(str(xml))  # <Element 'Person' at 0x00497A80>
```

Comment: In Python 2 `ElementTree.tostring()` also generates a bytestring. The `str` type *is a bytestring* in Python 2 (Python 3's `str` type is called `unicode` in Python 2).

Comment: That feature was only added to the Python 3 version, and not backported to Python 2. If it was, you'd get a `unicode` string back.

Answer (score 4):

## Non-Latin Answer Extension

Extension to [@Stevoisiak's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48671499/2333021) and dealing with non-Latin characters. Only one way will display the non-Latin characters to you. The one method is different on both Python 3 and Python 2.

**Input**

```
xml = ElementTree.fromstring('<Person Name="크리스" />')
xml = ElementTree.Element("Person", Name="크리스")  # Read Note about Python 2
```

> NOTE: In Python 2, when calling the `toString(...)` code, assigning `xml` with `ElementTree.Element("Person", Name="크리스")`will raise an error...
>
> `UnicodeDecodeError: 'ascii' codec can't decode byte 0xed in position 0: ordinal not in range(128)`

**Output**

```
ElementTree.tostring(xml)
# Python 3 (크리스): b'<Person Name="&#53356;&#47532;&#49828;" />'
# Python 3 (John): b'<Person Name="John" />'

# Python 2 (크리스): <Person Name="&#53356;&#47532;&#49828;" />
# Python 2 (John): <Person Name="John" />


ElementTree.tostring(xml, encoding='unicode')
# Python 3 (크리스): <Person Name="크리스" />             <-------- Python 3
# Python 3 (John): <Person Name="John" />

# Python 2 (크리스): LookupError: unknown encoding: unicode
# Python 2 (John): LookupError: unknown encoding: unicode

ElementTree.tostring(xml, encoding='utf-8')
# Python 3 (크리스): b'<Person Name="\xed\x81\xac\xeb\xa6\xac\xec\x8a\xa4" />'
# Python 3 (John): b'<Person Name="John" />'

# Python 2 (크리스): <Person Name="크리스" />             <-------- Python 2
# Python 2 (John): <Person Name="John" />

ElementTree.tostring(xml).decode()
# Python 3 (크리스): <Person Name="&#53356;&#47532;&#49828;" />
# Python 3 (John): <Person Name="John" />

# Python 2 (크리스): <Person Name="&#53356;&#47532;&#49828;" />
# Python 2 (John): <Person Name="John" />
```

Comment: Good call out on Non-Latin characters. I've updated my post to mention this.

Answer (score 2):

I had the same problem in Python 3.8 and none of the previous answers solved it. The issue is that ElementTree is both the name of a module and of a class within it. Using an alias makes it clear:

```
from xml.etree.ElementTree import ElementTree
import xml.etree.ElementTree as XET
...
ElementTree.tostring(...)  # Attribute-error
XET.tostring(...)          # Works
```

Comment: result is not a string

Answer (score 1):

**Input Sample File Content:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<UPDATE>
<DATA><SET_DOC ID="249865"/></DATA>
</UPDATE>
```

**To String approach code for specific element:**

```
import lxml.etree as ET

samplexml = ET.parse(r"D:\sample.xml")

sampleroot = samplexml.getroot()

for dataElement in sampleroot.iter('DATA'):
    updatext = ET.tostring(dataElement)
    print(updatext)
```

**Output:**

```
b'<DATA><SET_DOC ID="249865"/></DATA>\n'
```

Answer (score 0):

If you just need this for debugging to see how the XML looks like, then instead of `print(xml.etree.ElementTree.tostring(e))` you can use `dump` like this:

```
xml.etree.ElementTree.dump(e)
```

And this works both with `Element` and `ElementTree` objects as `e`, so there should be no need for `getroot`.

The [documentation of `dump`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/xml.etree.elementtree.html#xml.etree.ElementTree.dump) says:

> `xml.etree.ElementTree.dump(elem)`
>
> Writes an element tree or element structure to `sys.stdout`. This function should be used for debugging only.
>
> The exact output format is implementation dependent. In this version, it’s written as an ordinary XML file.
>
> `elem` is an element tree or an individual element.
>
> *Changed in version 3.8*: The `dump()` function now preserves the attribute order specified by the user.