# Reading an xml file and converting it to a string

Tags: xml

I would like to read an xml file then convert it to a string.

I tried the following:

```
et = ET.parse('file.xsd')
xml_str = ET.tostring(et, encoding='unicode')
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
LookupError: unknown encoding: unicode
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Converting a Python XML ElementTree to a String](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33814607/converting-a-python-xml-elementtree-to-a-string)

Comment: What package are you using? Are you using Python 2 or 3 ?

Comment: Python 2.7 im using xml.etree.ElementTree

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```py
xml_str = ET.tostring(et, encoding='utf-8')
```

or:

```
xml_str = ET.tostring(et).decode()
```

or

```py
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET
from xml.etree.ElementTree import tostring

tree = ET.parse('file.xsd')
tree = tree.getroot()

xml_str = tostring(tree)
xml_str = xml_str.lower()
tree= ET.fromstring(xml_str)
```

Comment: tried both. im getting the same error: 'ElementTree' object has no attribute 'tag'

Comment: yes............

Comment: Ok - last try - try the third option.