# How to create time series graph in Python which shows changes over the days or months?

Tags: python, pandas, graph

I have DataFrame where one column names "X" has value and second "Y" is timestamp, DataFrame looks like below:

[image]

The type of this column "X" is "int64", type of column "Y" is "object". 
My question is how can I create time series chart for these columns in my DataFrame.

I would like achieve something like below, nevetheles graph below concerns a time series over the years and I need changes over the days or months:

[image: me]

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already read you dataset into arrays named X and Y, For you x-axis you can generate an numpy array

```
x_axis_arr = np.arange(len(Y))
```

Then, after you plot with matplotlib, you can change the x-axis labels with

```
plt.plot(X, x_axis_arr)
plt.xticks(Y)
```

You might have to convert Y to a string array beforehand

Comment: how to convert Y to a string array ?

Comment: check out https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3204614/how-to-change-any-data-type-into-a-string-in-python